# Is there a way in SQL to sum the time spent of all the 'start' to 'end' processes who has the same id?

Tags: sql

Is there a way in SQL to sum the time spent of all the 'start' to 'end' processes of the same id?

```
id | b | timestamp
11| start | 1563794104895
11| intercepted | 1563794104898
11| end | 1563794104899
11| somethingelse | 1563794104999
11| start | 1563794105895
11| intercepted | 1563794106898
11| end | 1563794107899
12| start | 1563794104895
12| intercepted | 1563794104898
12| end | 1563794104899
```

Comment: with SQL Server, maybe you can try partition by with row_number. and get two row_number filter by b, one is ASC and another DESC, and join them based on Id, after that do minus.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a self join for the start and end and calculate the difference

```
select s.id, e.timestamp - s.timestamp
from the_table s
  join the_table e on s.id = e.id and e.b = 'end'
where s.b = 'start';
```

This assumes that there is always exactly one row with `start` and exactly one row with `end`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
with

group_ids as (
    select
        *,
        row_number() over(  partition by
                                id,
                                b
                            order by
                                timestamp) as rn
    from
        <your_table_name>
    where
        b in ('start', 'end')
)

select
    gi1.id,
    sum(gi2.timestamp - gi1.timestamp) as total_spend
from
    group_ids as gi1
    join group_ids as gi2 on    gi1.id = gi2.id
                                and gi1.rn = gi2.rn
                                and gi2.b = 'end'
where
    gi1.b = 'start'
group by
    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()`.  Assuming the values are interleaved correctly:

```
select id, sum(next_timestamp - timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             lead(timestamp) over (partition by id order by timestamp) as next_timestamp
      from t
      where b in ('start', 'end')
     ) t
where b = 'start'
group by id;
```